# Checking for isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism

What is given is  the group $R$.

G(R)

Prove that $R$ is isomorphic to $G$ by first giving an formula for a map $ϕ:R→G$, and checking that your map.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I know how to use it. I need to solve the question. do you have any idea or no?

Comment: Do you know the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Yes, i read aabout it, but this matrix form confusing me

Comment: The obvious map is to take the equivalence class of $\theta$ and map it to $\pmatrix{\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)}$; can you show that is well-defined and bijective and respects group operations?

Comment: There are a few ways to show a homomorphism is an isomorphism. You can show that the kernel is trivial (it only contains the identity), you can show that the homomorphism is bijective (surjective and injective), or you can show it has a well-defined inverse. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Let matrices of $G$ be denoted as $M(\theta)$, in which we just plug in $\theta$ for each entry in the rotation matrix. Just define $\phi : R \to G$ as $\phi(x):=M(x)$. First let's check this is a group homomorphism:

$$\phi(x+y)=M(x+y)=M(x)\cdot M(y)=\phi(x)\cdot\phi(y)$$

which follows from the fact that $M(\theta)$ is a rotation matrix. Note that the identity in $G$ is given by
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(0) & -\sin(0)\\ \sin(0)& \cos(0)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi n) & -\sin(2 \pi n)\\ \sin(2 \pi n)& \cos(2 \pi n)\end{bmatrix}$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, the kernel of $\phi$ is given as
$$Ker(\phi):=\{2\pi n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
We want to use the first isomorphism, but first we have to show $\phi$ is a surjection. $\phi$ is surjective if for all $M(\theta) \in G$, there exists some $x \in R$ such that $M(\theta)=\phi(x)$. This is trivial; since $\theta$ is a real number just choose $x=\theta$, then for all $M(\theta)$ we have that there exists an $x$ so that $\phi(x)=\phi(\theta)=M(\theta)$. Since $\phi$ is a surjection we can now use the first isomorphism theorem to assert
$$R/Ker(\phi)=R/H\approxeq G$$

Comment: Can you make the surjectivity more explicit? Also, the operator in $G$ should be $\cdot$, not $+$.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry Good catch, thanks. Fixed it and added some more about the surjection.

Comment: thank you. it waas very helpfull